# icCube load hangs on startup

Tags: iccube

We are using icCube 5.1.8 and are having problems with loads that seem to freeze. Until now only with 'Load on startup'. There are only 2 schemas that load on startup. Normally one loads in 1 minute and the other in 14 minutes. But now they both will not finish even after several hours. Last info in the log is 'LOAD SCHEMA (PHASE I) full-load started'

The machine is not busy on disk and no CPU. The Postgresql server it loads from is not running any query for the icCube server.

In the builder I can open a schema but if I want to browse a simple dimension it freezes.

I solved it by disabling 'load on startup' and deployed/loaded the schema from the builder.

We use 64 bits Java 1.8.0_77.

Is this a known problem? Other things I can check?

Thanks

Comment: are you running out of memory ? check iccube logs for this you'll see a lot of Full GC

Comment: No, we are not running out of memory (we were before but I stopped many loads). The Java settings are with 2GB max heap. According to icCube the schema's are using around 140MB and 100MB. For now I solved it by starting the load from the scheduler at icCube startup (with a delay of 15 seconds).

Comment: We have the same problem as Remco... If it can help troubleshooting...  We are using iccube on windows 2008R2 Web Server and use 64bits Java (build 1.8.0_77-b03)... What is your OS, Remco ?

Comment: We are running on Windows 2012 R2. We have same Java version as you, also 64 bits.

Comment: Remco, with the Community Edition the memory is limited to 512Mb  (just contact icCube support directly with the log files).

Comment: We have a paid version. How do I contact support directly?

I don't have the log files anymore. I will try to recreate the problem but a lot has changed in the load queries so I don't know if there is still a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more likely related to this [issue](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-241).

This will be fixed in the upcoming 5.2 version.

In the meantime, as a **workaround** use the scheduler to load the schema and ensure the load of the schema is starting after the "Docs" repository has been initialized.